# What does "arbitrary" mean in this context (emphasis mine)?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

> (1) Feminist  theorists  have  generalized  the  intuition  behind  such examples to show that it was **arbitrary** for Marx to measure the rate of exploitation by exclusive reference to the relation between the surplus produced and the wage paid to the worker.
>
> (2) Any such calculation ignores the contributions of the worker’s spouse to what he produces, which Marx **arbitrarily** takes to be the worker’s "own".
>
> (3) For Marx to make the buck stop with the wage-laborer, as far as measuring exploitation is concerned, is **arbitrary**.
>
> *- Moral Foundations of Politics by Ian Shapiro*

What does arbitrary means in these sentences?
Does it mean "random" or it means "Marx choose it without considerin other people's wishes"?

[image: Moral Foundations of Politics by Ian Shapiro]

[image: Moral Foundations of Politics by Ian Shapiro]

Comment: Did you look up "arbitrary" in a dictionary?

Comment: Of course I did. But i need  context-specific interpretation for this word.
I mean what Marx did by making "arbitrary" choices. Did he choose it randomly? Or something else?

Comment: If you have looked it up in a dictionary,  then please  include that in your question.  The answer to your comment is that he chose "arbitrarily" (in the dictionary definition "personal whim")  You need to explain how the dictionary definition doesn't help you understand